# How can I get the signature image from this signature pad with Vuejs + Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hi I have this signtaure pad with Vuejs:

[Signature pad code](https://codesandbox.io/s/n5qjp3oqv4?file=/src/App.vue)

I am trying to send this data into a controller to store it, but when I do this:

```
const { isEmpty, data } = this.$refs.signaturePad.saveSignature();
console.log(isEmpty);
console.log(data);

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('signtaure', this.$refs.signaturePad.saveSignature());

axios.post('/api/employee/update/27141399-8?api_token='+App.apiToken, formData, config)
.then(function (response) {
 currentObj.success = response.data.success;
})
```

If I check the console.log() it displays this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABioAAAJxCAYAAADcoOoFAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeF7s3c+LrUmaF/AYN25GqkXGndbIbEQYSxQUV+WAi9lIzT8g1S5ddbkQXAhVsxSErlq7qGpcupgqcCHCYNfGhQhjLcQfMM604CC6GAsFR8Fp+eL7jNGnT96b92bmiXif83khOXnvPXki4vNEZla93xMRPzNcBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAIFFAj+zqF3NEiBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgSGoMIkIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBJYJCCqW0WuYAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQEFSYAwQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgMAyAUHFMnoNEyBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAoIKc4AAAQIECBAgQIA
```

I check the laravel controller to get the file like this:

```
  $request->signature;
```

And it is empty.. a blank value so I wonder how can I send the base_64 image with vuejs to the controller because how I am doing it does not work

Comment: If this is your real code, you have a typo `signtaure` in `formData.append`

Comment: Yes I added formData.append because I trying to send the image or signature image to the controller with Post @julianstark999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You append the signature to the formdata object like this:

```js
formData.append('signtaure', this.$refs.signaturePad.saveSignature());
```

In the laravel controller you're checking for the `signature` property on the request object.

Notice the typo you've made within the append function? `signtaure` != `signature`.

@julianstark999 also made a comment about this, but I think you misinterpreted his comment, so I'm explaining it again :)

Comment: Ahh I got you @JadordeVries hehe but I have another issuse why do I receive [object Object]?

Comment: Where do you receive [object Object]? I need some more info on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the **data** which is base64 to Javascript **File** object, then append the **File** object to FormData.

```
const { isEmpty, data } = this.$refs.signaturePad.saveSignature();

// convert base64 to File object
const file = new File(
  [Uint8Array.from(btoa(data), (m) => m.codePointAt(0))],
  'filename.png',
  { type: 'image/png' }
);

// append File to FormData
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('signtaure', file);
```